# Restrict Formatting and Editing - MS 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am using restrict Formatting and Editing. I have chosen 'Filling in Forms' in the Editing Restriction drop down tab. I have chosen this one so that I can have boxes to tick, although by choosing this I cannot change the Font for the other half of my Form that needs to be filled out.

The Font is stuck on Times Roman and does not match my sub headings which is Arial. When I have unrestricted my Document I can type in Arial, although when I restrict this document the font goes back to Times Roman and I am unable to change it .

Please help?